# Add JsonArray to JsonObject

Tags: java, json, arrays

I googled a lot today for this subject. But I can't find it, How can I add a JSONArray to a JSONObject?

Because everytime I do this I get this error: Stackoverflow

```
        JSONObject fillBadkamerFormaatFromContentlet(Structure structure, String formaat) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();

    BadkamerFormaat badkamerFormaat = new BadkamerFormaat();
    BadkamerTegel badkamerTegel;
    List<Contentlet> contentlets = getContentletsByStructure(structure);
    badkamerFormaat.formaat = formaat;
    badkamerFormaat.tegels = new ArrayList<BadkamerTegel>();

    try {
        jsonObject.put("formaat", formaat); 
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e1);
    }

    for(Contentlet contentlet : contentlets) {
        badkamerTegel = new BadkamerTegel();
        badkamerTegel.naam = contentlet.getStringProperty(ParameterNames.toolBetegelVeldNaam);
        try {
            badkamerTegel.afbeeldingTegel = contentlet.getBinary(ParameterNames.toolBetegelVeldTegelAfbeelding).getPath();
            badkamerTegel.afbeeldingBadkamer = contentlet.getBinary(ParameterNames.toolBetegelVeldBadkamerAfbeelding).getCanonicalPath();
            arr.put(badkamerTegel.toJSON());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }   
    }

    try {
        jsonObject.put("aoColumnDefs",arr);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return jsonObject;          
}
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:248)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
at com.dotmarketing.util.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:953)
```

The JSON I want: Only the last JsonArray is going wrong:

```
{
           "wand": [
        {
            formaat: 'vierkant15x15'
            tegels: [
                    {naam: '', imgThumb: '/bla/bla.png', largeImg: '/bla/bla2.png'}
                    ,{naam: '', imgThumb: '/bla/bla.png', largeImg: '/bla/bla2.png'}
                    ]
        }
        ,

        {
            formaat: 'vierkant17x15'
            tegels: [
                    {naam: '', imgThumb: '/bla/bla.png', largeImg: '/bla/bla2.png'}
                    ,{naam: '', imgThumb: '/bla/bla.png', largeImg: '/bla/bla2.png'}
                    ]
        }
    ]
```

,
            "vloer": [
            {
                formaat: 'vierkant10x15'
                tegels: [
                        {naam: '', imgThumb: '/bla/bla.png', largeImg: '/bla/bla2.png'}
                        ,{naam: '', imgThumb: '/bla/bla.png', largeImg: '/bla/bla2.png'}
                        ]
            }
            ,

```
        {
            formaat: 'vierkant45x15'
            tegels: [
                    {naam: '', imgThumb: '/bla/bla.png', largeImg: '/bla/bla2.png'}
                    ,{naam: '', imgThumb: '/bla/bla.png', largeImg: '/bla/bla2.png'}
                    ]
        }
    ]
```

}

Comment: Hmm.. Also the person who answerd he, his option didn't work for me!

Comment: i think it may be a bug in the json impl you are using.  it _looks_ like you are using the API correctly from the code you have provided.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think it is a problem(aka. bug) with the [API](http://dotcms.com/docs/latest/javadocs/com/dotmarketing/util/json/JSONArray.html) you are using.  `JSONArray` implements `Collection` (the json.org implementation from which this API is derived does *not* have JSONArray implement Collection).  And `JSONObject` has an overloaded `put()` method which takes a Collection and wraps it in a `JSONArray` (thus causing the problem).  I think you need to force the other `JSONObject.put()` method to be used:

```
    jsonObject.put("aoColumnDefs",(Object)arr);
```

You should file a bug with the vendor, pretty sure their `JSONObject.put(String,Collection)` method is broken.

Answer (score 28):

here is simple code

```
List <String> list = new ArrayList <String>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        array.put(list.get(i));
}
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
try {
    obj.put("result", array);
} catch (JSONException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
pw.write(obj.toString());
```

Comment: PrintWriter object

Answer (score 7):

Your list:

```
List<MyCustomObject> myCustomObjectList;
```

Your JSONArray:

```
// Don't need to loop through it. JSONArray constructor do it for you.
new JSONArray(myCustomObjectList)
```

Your response:

```
return new JSONObject().put("yourCustomKey", new JSONArray(myCustomObjectList));
```

Your post/put http body request would be like this:

```
    {
        "yourCustomKey: [
           {
               "myCustomObjectProperty": 1
           },
           {
               "myCustomObjectProperty": 2
           }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm starting to learn about this myself, being very new to android development and I found this video very helpful.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcotbMLjlA4

It specifically covers to to get JSONArray to JSONObject at 19:30 in the video.

Code from the video for JSONArray to JSONObject:

```
JSONArray queryArray = quoteJSONObject.names();

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < queryArray.length(); i++){
    list.add(queryArray.getString(i));
}

for(String item : list){
    Log.v("JSON ARRAY ITEMS ", item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try below a simple solution:

```
JsonObject body=new JsonObject();
body.add("orders", (JsonElement) orders);
```

whenever my JSON request is like:

```
{
      "role": "RT",
      "orders": [
        {
          "order_id": "ORDER201908aPq9Gs",
          "cart_id": 164444,
          "affiliate_id": 0,
          "orm_order_status": 9,
          "status_comments": "IC DUE - Auto moved to Instruction Call Due after 48hrs",
          "status_date": "2020-04-15",
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonElement