# JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json

I get following error:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Here is the Android and PHP code I have:

```
private void eventUpdatePoint(String eventStatus,int lat,int lon){

    JSONParser jsonParserEUP = new JSONParser(); 
        try
        {   
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longtitude", Integer.toString(lon))); 
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", Integer.toString(lat)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eventstatus", eventStatus));
            String url_updatePoint = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/event_update_point.php";
            JSONObject json = jsonParserEUP.makeHttpRequest(url_updatePoint,"POST", params);
            Log.d("Response", json.toString()); 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("ERROR:","ERROR:"    + e.getClass().getName() + ":" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

php code:

```
$response = array(); if (isset($_POST['longtitude']) && isset($_POST['latitude']) &&isset($_POST['eventstatus'])) { 
    $longtitude = $_POST['longtitude']; 
    $latitude = $_POST['latitude']; 
    $eventstatus = $_POST['eventstatus'];

    $e_id=0;
    $score=0;


    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php'; 

    $db = new DB_CONNECT(); 

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM cordinates WHERE longtitude=$longtitude AND latitude=$latitude") or die(mysql_error()); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

            $e_id = $row["id"];  
        } 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT score FROM point WHERE e_id=$e_id") or die(mysql_error()); 

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

            $score = $row["score"];  
        } 
        if($eventstatus=="inc")
        {   
            $score+=10;
            $result = mysql_query("UPDATE point SET score=$score where e_id=$e_id") or die(mysql_error());  
            $response["success"] = 1; 
             $response["message"] ="Score point increased";
        }
        else if($eventstatus=="dec")
        {   
            $score-=10;
            $result = mysql_query("UPDATE point SET score=$score where e_id=$e_id") or die(mysql_error());
            $response["success"] = 0; 
             $response["message"] ="Score point decreased";
        }
    } 
    echo json_encode($response);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142238/add-jsonarray-to-jsonobject

Comment: plz add string which u are getting in response from server with question to get more help

Comment: @beyaz, did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The webservice you are using returns a JSONArray. You have to use an object of type JSONArray to store it. You can't use a JSONObject.

Change this line:

```
JSONObject json = jsonParserEUP.makeHttpRequest(url_updatePoint,"POST", params);
```

...to this:

```
JSONArray json = jsonParserEUP.makeHttpRequest(url_updatePoint,"POST", params);
```

Comment: so I have to implement my JsonParser for JsonArray? Cuz, Jsonparser return Json Object

Comment: Basically, yes. I don't know which parser you use. If you implemented it yourself, then you have to modify it to parse the JSON as an array. If you're using some library, then it probably has a way of doing it - just read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Log your response.If it starts with"[" and ends with "]",you have to store it in variable of type "JSONArray".With attention to your log,your response must be a "JSONArray",so simply save your response in a variable of type "JSONArray".

Comment: i did not get it clearly. I got error when I make HttpRequest. How can I do variable of type "JSONArray" when request?