# Create complex Json Object

Tags: json, scala

I need to create a json object, i use play-json lib for Scala.

I have this code:

```
import play.api.libs.json
import play.api.libs.json._

object Start {
    def main(args: Array[String])
    {
        val GraphDbJson= Json.obj("name"->"father","nodeid"->1,"children"->Json.arr(func1))
        println(Json.prettyPrint(GraphDbJson))
    }

    def func1():JsValue=
    {
        var JObjChildrenNodes=Seq[JsValue]()

        JObjChildrenNodes :+ Json.obj("name"->"child1","nodeid"->2,"children"->Json.arr())
        JObjChildrenNodes :+ Json.obj("name"->"child2","nodeid"->3,"children"->Json.arr())     
        Json.toJson(JObjChildrenNodes)
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
{
    "name" : "father",
    "nodeid" : 1,
    "children" : [ [ ] ]
}
```

how can I pass an json array ? Why the return value of func1 is empty?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I did create that in this link, used the or [Create nested Json][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21377682/1820466

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `:+` with `+:=` (since the default implementation of `Seq` is `List` you should not use `:+=`).

`Seq` is immutable. With `:+` you are creating a new `Seq`.

So you should use `nodes = nodes :+ Json.obj(...)` instead of `nodes :+ Json.obj(...)`, or just `nodes :+= Json.obj(...)` (see the last part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1483744/406435)).

You could use mutable collection like `mutable.Seq` with `+=` operation: `nodes += Json.obj(...)`.

I would prefer to create a collection this way:

```
nodes = Seq(
  Json.obj(...),
  Json.obj(...)
)
```

Note that default implementation of `Seq` is `List` and append (`:+`) operation on `List` is very [inefficient](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) - you should use prepend - `+:` and `+:=`.

Alternative solution: there is `Json.writes` (and `Json.reads`) in `Play`, so you could create a class and convert it to `JSON` this way:

```
case class MyNode(name: String, nodeid: Int, children: Seq[MyNode] = Nil)
implicit lazy val myNodeWrites = Json.writes[MyNode]

val myNode = MyNode("father", 1, MyNode("child1", 2) :: MyNode("child2", 3) :: Nil)
val graphDbJson = Json.toJson(myNode)
Json.prettyPrint(graphDbJson)
// {
//   "name" : "father",
//   "nodeid" : 1,
//   "children" : [ {
//     "name" : "child1",
//     "nodeid" : 2,
//     "children" : [ ]
//   }, {
//     "name" : "child2",
//     "nodeid" : 3,
//     "children" : [ ]
//   } ]
// }
```

Also: there is a error in your code: you should replace `Json.arr(func1)` with `func1`:  `Json.arr(func1)` creates an array of arrays, since `func1` already returns a json array.

Comment: @faster2b: Note that you don't have to work with `Json.obj` - see update in my answer.

Comment: @faster2b: you should remove `Json.arr`, see update in my answer.

Comment: @faster2b: I've just tested `case class` code - works fine. Result: `{"name":"father","nodeid":1,"children":[{"name":"child1","nodeid":2,"children":[]},{"name":"child2","nodeid":3,"children":[]}]}`