# Send Json params to Volley library

Tags: android, json, android-volley

anyone know how can I send a JSON param to  Volley ? Seeing the library, I watch the methods getParams that return a Map , but I need to send a Json with the form

```
{"medias" : [1,2,3,4,5] }
```

but if I send it with the getParams method,  my server receive some like this :  "medias" : "[1,2,3,4,5]" (the second part as a string)

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JsonObjectRequest` in Volley allows you to pass your `JSONObject` into the constructor.  Just create a `JSONObject`, add your `JSONArray` and use it to create your `JsonObjectRequest`.

Here's an example of how to create a JSONArray:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13468303/736496