# How to post data in my json format

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-volley

I am new in android and confuse in post data in json format using volley lib.
My Json param like:

```
             {
                key
                comKey
                addLeadArray
                [{
                    key                                 
                    autoid
                    images[image1,image2...]
                    audio

                 }
                 {
                key                                 
                autoid
                images[image1,image2...]
                audio

             }
             {
                key                                 
                autoid
                images[image1,image2...]
                audio

             }.....]                    
            }
```

I am trying code:

```
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(); 
        object.put("key", "1");
        object.put("comKey", "2");
        ................
        JSONObject addLeadArrayObj= new JSONObject();
        AddLeadArray.put("key", "1");
        AddLeadArray.put("autoid", "34");
        ................
        object.put("addLeadArray", addLeadArrayObj);
```

But its create {{}} and I want to make json object for above json formate. what can I do please help me and pls give code snippt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is creating JSONObject AddLeadArray and putting it in the main JsonObject.

AddLeadArray is an array, so make it an object of JSONArray instead of JSONObject.

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(); 
    object.put("key", "1");
    object.put("comKey", "2");
    ................
    // Create JSONArray
    JSONArray addLeadArrayObj= new JSONArray();
    // Create JSONObject for jsonArray
    JSONObject object2 = new JSONObject(); 

    object2.put("key", "1");
    object2.put("autoid", "34");

    // put object2 in addLeadArray 
    addLeadArrayObj.put(object2);
    // put addLeadArray in main jsonobject 
    object.put("addLeadArray", addLeadArrayObj);
```

Refer more here: [Add JsonArray to JsonObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142238/add-jsonarray-to-jsonobject)

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); // Or use new GsonBuilder().create();
MyType target = new MyType();
String json = gson.toJson(target); // serializes target to Json
MyType target2 = gson.fromJson(json, MyType.class); // deserializes json into target2
```

If the object that your are serializing/deserializing is a **ParameterizedType** (i.e. contains at least one type parameter and may be an array) then you must use the `toJson(Object, Type)` or `fromJson(String, Type)` method.

Here is an example for serializing and deserialing a ParameterizedType:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
List<String> target = new LinkedList<String>();
target.add("blah");

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(target, listType);
List<String> target2 = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
```

Here is the [Gson Help](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html).

Comment: i am not know about Gson lib in my case how to use it.

Comment: Bro, you can read its documentation. It is easy. It takes one time effort. Only you need to make your custom class for your **JSON** parameters.