# Insert object to beginnig of JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json

I just had to insert an JSONObject `jsonVariables` to the beginning of an existing JSONArray("children" of `tree`).
I was wondering that I couldn't find a simple way to do so. I ended up doing it like this:

```
JSONObject jsonVariables= getSomeJSONObject();
JSONObject tree = getTreeNode(givenSection);
JSONArray tmpArray = new JSONArray();
tmpArray.put(jsonVariables);
for (int i = 0; i < tree.getJSONArray("children").length(); i++) {
        tmpArray.put(tree.getJSONArray("children").get(i));
}
tree.put("children", tmpArray);
```

Did I oversee a method to insert directly to the beginning of a JSONArray or does this really not exists?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142238/add-jsonarray-to-jsonobject

Comment: I actually need exactly the opposite. How to put a JSONObject to index 0 of an JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

JSONArray contain add method not put method.

you can use like this

```
JSONObject jsonVariables= getSomeJSONObject();
JSONObject tree = getTreeNode(givenSection);
JSONArray tmpArray = new JSONArray();
tmpArray.add(jsonVariables);
for (int i = 0; i < tree.getJSONArray("children").length(); i++) {
        tmpArray.add(tree.getJSONArray("children").get(i));
}
tree.put("children", tmpArray);
```

Comment: I'm aware that put overwrites an existing array, but as jsonVariables is the first object that goes in there it doesn't matter in this case.