# How to add ["xxx"] to JSONObject, it adds escape character

Tags: java

```
final String gene = "[" + "\"" + "xxx" + "\"" + "]";
String jsonString = new JSONObject()
                .put("type", "Clinical")
                .put("tests", gene).toString();
```

To my jsonString it adds escape character \ 
    `{"tests":"[\"PR20065.01\"]","type":"Clinical"}`

I want to post
    `{"tests":["PR20065.01"],"type":"Clinical"}`

*I am new to java

Comment: Why are you pre-formatting the text?  The `JSONObject` will format it for you.  If you want to add an array of values to the `tests` key, then you should be using a `JSONArray` object

Comment: You should use JSONArray for this:
Please read
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142238/add-jsonarray-to-jsonobject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you're adding the String `["xxx"]` as the value for `tests`, when you actually want a `JSONArray`. Notice the entirety of the `tests` value is in quotes. This is because it's literally a string that looks like an array. You can't have `"` in JSON, so they're escaped.

You instead want to create a `JSONArray` object, which you can then add . I'm not sure what library you're using here, but I assume the Android SDK. You should be able to fix your problem by just passing the String value to a new `JSONArray` (although I've never worked with the Android SDK, so I'm not positive that this works):

```
String jsonString = new JSONObject()
                .put("type", "Clinical")
                .put("tests", new JSONArray("xxx")).toString();
```

Comment: Thank you so much        :-)

Comment: You're welcome! You should mark this as the accepted answer if it's doing what you want.